# NSString To NSDate Conversion Not Working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I Tried to convert from NSString to NSdate but its not wroking. See my Code. Its getting out put as "1991-01-04 18:30:00 +0000". can any one help me. thanks in advance

```
NSString *selectedDateString =@"03/28/1991";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate * selectedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:selectedDateString];
NSLog(@"selectedDate-->%@",selectedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only format you need to use, I advice you to use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` instead of `dateFormat` and set the dateStyle to `NSDateFormatterStyleShort` while the timeStyle to `NSDateFormatterStyleNone`. This is bullet proof and localization friendly: no matter which locale your user use the date will always be displayed with the right format (for the user).

Comment: Great advice for displaying the string, however this is for converting a known format into an NSDate object.